# GParted stuck, details say resize was successful

Tags: partitioning, gparted, resize

I'm trying to resize the NTFS partition on an internal hard drive (not a drive that has an operating system installed, just extra storage). The Details say:

```
successfully resized NTFS on device '/dev/sdb1
```

But now it is stuck on the applying pending operations page seemingly doing nothing.

Any idea what's going on?

(Using a xubuntu 14.10 installer disk)

Comment: You can expand the details pane on the _applying pending operations_ window to see what is currently running.  Further you might check to see if there are any ntfs operations still running with a command like `ps -ef | grep -i ntfs`.

Comment: Wow Acceptance after 3 years!  Thanks!  Question upvoted!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just press the <kbd>Close</kbd> button. That's all.

[image]